# all rows change to NA after filtering R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a large dataframe consisting of five columns.

When I try to filter on one of the columns another column every row in another column is changed to NA. The column I'm filtering on is VehicleEvent, Location is the column receiving the NA substitution.

```
str(datain)
'data.frame':   7551105 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ DiagnosticIDs   : chr  "2,0,3,1,774,775,810,744,951,947" "2,0,3,1,774,775,7,718,720,951,837,810,744,947" "2,0,3,1,774,775,7,810,744,951,947" NA ...
 $ DiagnosticValues: chr  "28.211,48284.435,31647,7650.75,0,0,0,1,1,-73" "28.272,48290.34,31650,7651.2,0,0,550,0,0,54,0,0,1,-81" "28.272,48290.34,31650,7651.2,0,0,550,0,1,1,-81" NA ...
 $ DriverName      : chr  "" "" "" NA ...
 $ IgnitionOn      : chr  "true" "true" "true" NA ...
 $ Latitude        : num  51.5 51.5 51.5 51.5 51.5 ...
 $ Longitude       : num  -0.462 -0.462 -0.463 -0.463 -0.463 ...
 $ Location        : chr  "" "Parking area" "Dispatch" NA ...
 $ Time            : num  1.52e+09 1.52e+09 1.52e+09 1.52e+09 1.52e+09 ...
     some columns not of interest omitted
 $ AlertId         : chr  NA NA NA "6fbc400e-1ae5-11e8-9eee-7845c4f0a3d7" ...
 $ AlertType       : chr  NA NA NA "Exited" ...
 $ VehicleEvent    : chr  NA NA NA "fabb4fcb-c254-4a13-8f9c-a3307a4ba63b" ...
 $ MessageType     : chr  NA NA NA "InsightAlertMessage" ...


str(datadf)
'data.frame':   104136 obs. of  6 variables:
$ Location    : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
$ Longitude   : num  -0.483 -0.462 -0.466 -0.464 -0.464 ...    
$ Latitude    : num  51.5 51.5 51.5 51.5 51.5 ...
$ AlertId     : chr  "ae22e47c-47c4-11e8-9513-7845c4f0a3d7" "3e13ccbc-47c6-11e8-a72e-7845c4f0a3d7" "5428da40-47c8-11e8-b59f-7845c4f0a3d7" "2fcd3fa8-47df-11e8-85a9-7845c4f0a3d7" ...
$ AlertType   : chr  "Exited" "Exited" "Exited" "Exited" ...
$ VehicleEvent: chr  "792d6964-6ba1-4f98-9b63-5c9e194fff6d" "792d6964-6ba1-4f98-9b63-5c9e194fff6d" "792d6964-6ba1-4f98-9b63-5c9e194fff6d" "792d6964-6ba1-4f98-9b63-5c9e194fff6d" ...
```

There are no non-ACSII characters in the data (it's all extracted from XML if that means anything). All  commas, trailing spaces, full-stop(period) and slashes have been removed from Location in case they has caused this.

The columns have been renamed (just in case there was something else going on using the same names).

I have tried pretty much everything I can think of including ...

```
datadf <- datain %>%
    filter(AlertType == "Exited" &
           VehicleEvent == "792d6964-6ba1-4f98-9b63-5c9e194fff6d") %>%
            select(Location, Latitude, Longitude)

datadf <- datain[datain$VehicleEvent == "792d6964-6ba1-4f98-9b63-5c9e194fff6d",]
```

That last one changes all columns to 'NA'.

Is the data in VehicleEvent so strange that it can't be handled...surely not. I have run out of ideas hence my request to the wider community.

Comment: I believe you really have NAs at these positions, you just don't expect them to be there, if your dataset is not too huge you can use `View(dataset)` on it from `RStudio` and explore from there.

Comment: For characters I find safer to use `%in%` rather than `==`. .. also in dplyr,  filter there is no need for & , a coma is enough. I would select some entries at random and check that the Location Data is correct and filter on that VehicleEvents.  Getting 10 entries at random with RStudio `View(sample_n(datain, 10)`. If everything is returned correctly then they might indeed be Na in the other entries

Comment: `==` returns NA when it encounters one for the variable you're comparing to the value, as @R.Prost said, you should be using `%in%` rather than `==` or use `subset` to subset your data.frame. Now, if every row is NA it means that none of the value of your variable is `"792d6964-6ba1-4f98-9b63-5c9e194fff6d"` (and so only the rows where ther is NA for the variable are returned) else it would also return the "right rows"

Comment: OK, the positions do not have NA in all records. See the str() prints from before and after.  The original dataset is 7551105 obs. of  19 variables. After the filter/selection it is 104136 obs. of  6 variables. The string ending in fff6d is definitely in there ...

Comment: I have just attempted this filter using `fdatadf <- datain %>%
+     filter(AlertType %in% c("Exited") &
+            VehicleEvent %in% c("792d6964-6ba1-4f98-9b63-5c9e194fff6d")) %>%
+             select(Location, Latitude, Longitude)` and still end up with a column of NA in Location.

Comment: at this point I guess you are getting slightly mad, I would try to rename the column, reforce it as character, change NA's to "missing" to make sure that if I get NA it is some filtering error rather than the actual value. Also `&` can simply be a coma in your filter selection or you can filter multiple times (that's what I usually do to avoid complexity and when speed is not an issue). So if after that you get NA then it is some error in the filtering but if you get missing then that's the actual values..

Comment: Not as mad as finding out that someone had changed the input and not told anybody since the initial test data. So in short thanks everybody. But the "problem" wasn't... and I had changed, column names, stripped out unusual charecters, changed the order of columns, ran 'unique' on columns,...  I now have 8 million rows of sensible data to try and cluster. Once again thanks folks.